# bash commands don't seem to run in .xinitrc

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, x11, awesome, xinput

I am trying to run some bash commands in my `.xinitrc` script, but the window manager starts without these commands running properly.

I run Arch Linux with the window manager is called "awesome", and I start it with `startx`. This is the entirety of my `~/.xinitrc` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ~/.xinitrc
#
# Executed by startx (run your window manager from here)

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]; then
  for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*; do
    [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
  done
  unset f
fi

xinput set-int-prop "TPPS/2 IBM Trackpoint" "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 8 1
xinput set-int-prop "TPPS/2 IBM Trackpoint" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 8 2
xinput set-int-prop "TPPS/2 IBM Trackpoint" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout" 8 200
xinput set-int-prop "TPPS/2 IBM Trackpoint" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes" 8 6 7 4 5

rfkill block bluetooth

# exec gnome-session
# exec startkde
# exec startxfce4
# ...or the Window Manager of your choice
exec awesome
```

As you may have noticed, I'm trying to shut down my Bluetooth and activate trackpoint scrolling on my laptop. Each of those `xinput` and `rfkill` commands work when entered manually, but nothing happens when I run `startx`.

What on earth is the problem here? :(

Comment: At least `rfkill` needs root privileges, if I'm not mistaken. Are you sure `rfkill block bluetooth` works on your system with user rights?

Comment: Are these commands producing any errors? Could it be that they're working, but something later in your session startup overrides these settings? Try launching just an xterm instead of a window manager, while you're testing that.

Comment: @Gilles I tried starting only xterm (I replaced `exec awesome` with `exec xterm`) but I am presented with a completely blank terminal with no errors...

Comment: @Marco `rfkill` does indeed require root privileges, but I assumed that `.xinitrc` was run as root. If I can't `rfkill` in `.xinitrc`, where should I run it?

Comment: @Joshua You should be able to type commands in this terminal. The `.xinitrc` is your session initialization file, it most assuredly is not executed as root. If you want something to be executed as root, it should be in the system startup, not in your session's startup.

Comment: @Gilles I see...Well, I'm using `systemd` which seems to deal with services rather than startup scripts, so any ideas where I can put it? I don't want to manually enter `rfkill` every time I reboot...

Comment: @Joshua I'm not familiar with Arch; there may well already be a configuration file under `/etc` where you can specify default Bluetooth settings. I recommend posting this as a separate question. If all else fails, you can put this command in [`/etc/rc.local`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Initscripts#.2Fetc.2Frc.local).

Answer (score 1):

Urgh...the underlying problem was really trivial.

`rfkill` requires root privileges, so it wouldn't run properly.

The reason my `xinput` commands didn't work was because of a typo in the device name. It should be "TrackPoint" not "Trackpoint". `xinput` just silently failed.

Damn it, that took way longer than I'm proud of.

Comment: How did you fix rfkill with root provileges?

Comment: @KarlMorrison IIRC I ended up blacklisting the Bluetooth module in /etc/modprobe.conf or /etc/modprobe.d/bluetooth.conf instead of using rfkill.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `~/.xsession-errors`. The output of `.xinitrc` is redirected there, so any errors that are encountered should show up there and will help you debugging your script.

Comment: There is no such file for me. I tried to `find` it as well...